# Windows 8.1: how to update Broadcom driver without using external drive

Tags: macbook-pro, bootcamp, windows

I am looking for a way to update a Broadcom driver without using BootCamp or external boot drive.

I have a Macbook pro mid-2012 (non-retina) and successfully had Windows 8.1 running on it, except it does not detect any ethernet and wifi devices.

I used Bootcamp through which I believe I got the latest Windows-support drivers and firmwares.

I do not have access to any external drive to build a boot drive and to any network which I might download softwares directly from a Windows partition. The entry point is the OS X partition.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score -1):

Download on Mac from http://www.broadcom.com/support/ethernet_nic/downloaddrivers.php

Depending on write support, copy to Windows partition from Mac or from Mac partition in Windows.

If direct install doesn't fix it, try uninstall from Device Manager, reboot & install again - seems to have worked for others.